# Is it possible to import a dart library into an .html asset?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I would like to include all my classes that extend PolymerElement in a library called custom_elements. This I can do.

After creation, I cannot see any mechanism as to how I can then import/reference the classes of this lbrary into the  src attribute of the dart script directive of an .html file as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Use polymer-element instead of element -->
<polymer-element name="my-element">
<template>
<p>Hello from inside of a custom element!</p>
<p>The counter is {{counter}}</p>
</template>

<script type="application/dart" src="my_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The script src="my_element.dart" SHOULD reference the file my_element.dart that resides in my custom_elements library, BUT I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO LET THE .html file see this library.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should have added information about in which directory the element's html is stored and in which package/directory your library is stored.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just enter the path to your library in the script tag, eg.:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="/packages/my_library/blah/my_element.dart"></script>
```

Comment: As far as I know there is still an open bug that prevents Polymer from working when the code-behind library contains the code for more than one element. You might also need to go up one level outside your app directory (weird but true) before going down through the `packages` directory depending on where the importing file is stored.